# xsl string tokenize duplicate value

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have String as O, T, A, F, M, I, S, R, A (Hedged), V, PFT when try to tokenize with comma separted I'm getting result as O T A F M I S R A Hedged V PFT with A getting duplicated and which is incorrect it should have A (Hedged) as one token.

I tried below xsl:
XML node will have value as O, T, A, F, M, I, S, R, A (Hedged), V, PFT

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<path>
<some>O, T, A, F, M, I, S, R, A (Hedged), V, PFT</some>
</path>

 <xsl:variable name="val" select="//path/some" />
<xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize($val, ', ')">
  <xsl:variable name="tokVal" select="."/>
<h2><xsl:value-of select="$tokVal"/></h2>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Expected output is O T A F M I S R A (Hedged) V PFT

Comment: If you wanted a string to start with you would need `<xsl:variable name="val" select="'O, T, A, F, M, I, S, R, A (Hedged), V, PFT'"/>`.

Comment: Updated my post I was just trying to put the block of code.

Comment: Consider to post a minimal but complete and executable example allowing us to reproduce the problem. I am afraid `select="O, T, A, F, M, I, S, R, A (Hedged), V, PFT"` is not a string at all. An unquoted `O` would try to select a child element named `O` of the context node and `A (Hedged)` would try to call a function named `A` with an argument formed by the selection of an element named `Hedged`.

Comment: Also, why are you using the EXSLT `str:tokenize` extension function in XSLT 2.0?

Comment: I have updated my original post. Basically, data is read from XML node.

Comment: @Daniel I have defined my name space as that : xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings

Comment: What I meant was that XSLT 2.0/XPath 2.0 already has the [`tokenize()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath-functions-20101214/#func-tokenize) built-in function. Are you sure you're using an XSLT 2.0 processor? Example: http://xsltransform.net/93dEHGG/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XSLT 2.0 and your finally posted XML input I can't reproduce the problem at http://xsltransform.net/bEzjRKJ, input is

```
<path>
<some>O, T, A, F, M, I, S, R, A (Hedged), V, PFT</some>
</path>
```

minimal XSLT is

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>Test</title>
        </head>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="some">
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '\s*,\s*')">
            <h2>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </h2>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

output is

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "XSLT-compat">
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Test</title>
   </head>
   <path>

      <h2>O</h2>
      <h2>T</h2>
      <h2>A</h2>
      <h2>F</h2>
      <h2>M</h2>
      <h2>I</h2>
      <h2>S</h2>
      <h2>R</h2>
      <h2>A (Hedged)</h2>
      <h2>V</h2>
      <h2>PFT</h2>

   </path>
</html>
```

rendering as

O

T

A

F

M

I

S

R

A (Hedged)

V

PFT

Comment: Thank you, that worked. String list was also having space in it which was causing the issue. Before tokenize, I have removed the spaces.